# Solving a Fredholm equation

Tags: integration, integral-equations, eigenfunctions

I'm trying to solve this form of Fredholm equation:

$$
g(v)=f(v)+\int\limits_{0}^{a} g(v_s)K(v,v_s)\mathrm{d} v_s,
$$
where,

- $f, K$ is a given function
- $K(v,v_s)=K_1(v-bv_s)+K_2(v+bv_s)$, where $b$ is a constant

Are there any methods or theorems that can solve this problem?

I know it is solvable when $K(v,v_s)=K(v-v_s)$, but it seems very hard to solve it when $K(v,v_s)=K_1(v-bv_s)+K_2(v+bv_s)$.

I would appreciate any hint or advises. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think there may be a closed form solution to this problem? Does the function obey special boundary conditions/ does the kernel vanish outside $(0,a)$? The simpler equation is solvable when the integration limits are $\pm\infty$, not when they are arbitrary unless there is something special to enable such a solution.

Comment: $$
g(v)=f_0(v)+\int\limits_{0}^{v_\mathrm{th}} g(v_s)\frac{e^{-\tfrac{\big[(v-v_\mathrm{init})-(1-v_\mathrm{leak})(v_s-v_\mathrm{init})\big]^2}{2v_\mathrm{step}^2}}+e^{-\tfrac{\big[(v+v_\mathrm{init})+(1-v_\mathrm{leak})(v_s-v_\mathrm{init})\big]^2}{2v_\mathrm{step}^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}v_\mathrm{step}}\mathrm{d} v_s,
$$
where, 
* $v_\mathrm{init}$, $v_\mathit{th}$, $v_\mathrm{step}$, $v_\mathrm{leak}$ are constant and
* $f_0$ has the following form:
$$
f_0(v)=delta(v-v_\mathrm{init})
$$

Comment: I'm trying to solve the above equation. The equation applies to diffusion of liquid initially at v_init(between very thin plates, expressed as a delta function). The reason why I set the kernel inside (0, v_th) is at 0 there is a wall so it reflects liquid and at v_th there is a absorber so once liquid passes it it cannot reverse into (0, v_th).

Comment: I also think it is most likely the closed form of solution may not exists. I just want to compare the solution and simulation measured values, so it doesn't matter whether the solution is  a closed-form solution or numerical method solution.